Interface excess free energy using spherical harmonics
I am a bit struggling to calculate a quantity involving spherical harmonics $Y_{lm}(\theta,\varphi)$. We parameterize as surface in spherical coordinates as:
\begin{equation}
\xi(\theta,\varphi) = R \sum_{l,m} a_{lm}Y_{lm}(\theta,\varphi)
\end{equation}
Where $Y_{lm}(\theta,\varphi)$, are the spherical harmonics.
The excess energy is defined as an intergal over the sphere of radius R:
\begin{equation}
\Phi= \frac{\gamma_0 R^2}{2} \int_\Omega |\nabla \xi(\theta,\varphi)|^2 \sin \theta \, d\theta d\varphi
\end{equation}
I need to show that:
\begin{equation}
\Phi= \frac{\gamma_0 R^2}{2} \sum_{l,m} |a_{lm}|^2 (l-1)(l+2)
\end{equation}
I suspected using green's identity to get $\Delta Y_{lm}$ to use the definition of spherical harmonics.
Reference paper : https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3013638
Formula used in paper.
Thank you very much.

Cross-posted to Math Stack Exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4952399/137524

The paper references the work of Rayleigh in his 1879 paper "On the Capillary Phenomena of Jets". If you dig through that paper, said paper actually includes (Appendix II, p. 95-97) a special case of the above calculation: specifically, the case of where the deformation is symmetric around the $z$-axis (and thus $a_{\ell 0}=0$). In particular, compare the desired result with Rayleigh's Eq. (36).
